# Is it possible to display the progress of a sort in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

My job involves a lot of sorting fields from very large files. I usually do this with the `sort` command in bash. Unfortunately, when I start a sort I am never really sure how long it is going to take. Should I wait a second for the results to appear, or should I start working on something else while it runs?

Is there any possible way to get an idea of how far along a sort has progressed or how fast it is working?

```
$ cut -d , -f 3 VERY_BIG_FILE | sort -du > output
```

Comment: It's working 'flat out'.  There isn't a reliable way to detect how far it has progressed and how much longer it has to run.  You might be able to poke around /proc for the sort and make some deductions, but probably not.

Comment: Maybe an alternative sort routine then? Most sort routines themselves (like QuickSort) at least have an idea of how far along the sort is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, GNU `sort` does not do progress reporting.

However, if are you using `sort` just to remove duplicates, and you don't actually care about the ordering, then there's a [more scalable way](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/awk1line.txt) of doing that:

```
awk '! a[$0]++'
```

This writes out the first occurrence of a line as soon as it's been seen, which can give you an idea of the progress.

Comment: Scalable... to all the RAM, then it's no longer scalable.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to give [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) a try, it should give you a pretty good idea of what is going on in your pipe in terms of throughput.

Example (untested) injecting `pv` before and after the `sort` command to get an idea of the throughput:

```
$ cut -d , -f 3 VERY_BIG_FILE | pv -cN cut | sort -du | pv -cN sort > output
```

**EDIT**: I missed the -u in your sort command, so calculating lines first to be able to get a percentage output is void. Removed that part from my answer.

Comment: While `pv` is a great tool, it only gives an idea how far we really are if you give it a `-s` option to tell it the total length.

Comment: @glglgl My example used `-s` before the edit, but as we cannot know the size after sort -u I removed it. The OP asked for a solution that at least helps determine _"how fast it is working"_, which `pv` does, in a way.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Could you explain exactly how `pv` without `s` helps determine how fast it is working? What kind of output can I expect to see from it? I'm trying to figure out whether it's worth killing my current `sort` process on a very large set of files to restart another piped through `pv`.

Comment: `pv` is great, but I don't see  how it would really help with sort since sort can't produce output until it has processed the entire input.

Answer (score -4):

You can execute your "sort" in background
you will get prompt and you can do other jobs

$sort ......  &    # (& means run in background )

Comment: While your statement is undoubtedly correct your answer has nothing to do with the question.